# How to restrict entering old date in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, date, angular6

My code as follows,

```
ngOnInit() {

    let now = new Date();

    this.date = formatDate(now, "dd/mm/yyyy",'en-US');
    console.log("dateFormat :",this.date);
}
```

My html:

```
   <input type="date" [min]={{date}} id="App_Date" class="form-control" formControlName="App_Date">
```

So here Im getting the current date & trying to assign for min. But it is not working. Could somebody please help me with this?

I need to restrict the user to stop entering old dates. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use `[min]="date"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to remove the timezone properties from the date object using `split`

```
ngOnInit() {

   let now = new Date();

   this.date =  new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
   console.log("dateFormat :",this.date);
}
```

And remove the curly brackets from the template

```
<input type="date" [min]="date" id="App_Date" class="form-control" formControlName="App_Date">
```

Comment: Cool. make sure to check as answer if this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Use direct `[min]="date"` instead of `[min]={{date}}` in view.

`<input type="date" [min]="date" id="App_Date" class="form-control" formControlName="App_Date">`